# How To Show Buttons Based on Value in a Column

Tags: php, laravel

I have a column in my table, with titled: sum_days

```
id | Name | Sum_Days | 
---+------+----------+
1  | Ed   |   3      |
2  | Jane |   4      |
3  | Rose |   2      |
```

I need to show sum_days onto the page with buttons, for example I want to show Ed's Sum of Days, 3 days so on the page will show three buttons based on the number in the table column.

I'm using Laravel code like this:

```
return <a href="employees/'.$st->id.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Day-'.$st->sum_days.'</a>';
```

But it's showing the whole data, not each button from the sum of the days. It should be

```
> [ButtonDay-1] [ButtonDay-2] [ButtonDay-3]
```

I was confused how to do it, any suggestion or help I would be thankful. Thank you.

Comment: Run throughout the loop of `id`s and assign thouse `id`s to links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put it inside a loop should do it :

```php
$links = '';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $st->sum_days; $i++) {
    $links .= '<a href="employees/' . $st->id . '" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Day-' . $i . '</a>';
}
return $links;
```

Comment: Dana Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot, a loop yes of-course. Thank you so much you save my life.